# Adding color via macro in excel

Tags: excel, colors, styling, fill, vba

I have 13 columns of information about our current inventory - preowned cars
They are sorted by make model year etc
I would like a macro to look at the 8th column (Make) and change the fill color of the entire row of alternating makes to yellow so they stand out in groups when printed
Makes may come and go and number of each make in inventory changes as well depending on purchases and sales. Of course it also needs to stop when it gets to the bottom of the data.
I have read a bunch of articles but haven't seen this particular concern addressed
Any help or points in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.
Am using Excel 2010

Answer (score 0):

Macros are not required. You can use conditional formatting. Assuming your data starts in row 2, set the conditional formatting formula for a cell in row 2 to the following

```
=MOD(SUM(IF($H2:$H9999<>OFFSET($H2:$H9999,1,0),1,0)),2)=0
```

and set the highlight for that condition as desired. Copy and paste format to the other cells. Adjust the lower bound as needed so you cover all your rows. This could be made dynamic too, but I didn't want to muddle the formula too much.

Comment: Wow - thank you! It worked perfectly. Will spend more time learning about this aspect.